# Use jQuery to change dropdown list option while firing Ajax operations

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, select, drop-down-menu

I need to change the dropdown list selection using jQuery. Unfortunately using the following code:

```
var value = "ARS";
jQuery("select[id^=lc_currency] option[value=" + value + "]").attr("selected","selected").change();
```

It only fires off one Ajax operation and does not fire off the remaining ones. Here is the code for the select box:

```
<select style="width:200px" name="lc_currency1" id="lc_currency1" onchange="localCurrencyChange('SGD',lcValues1,1)"> 
<option value="ARS">Argentine Peso (ARS)</option>
<option value="SGD" selected="selected">Singapore Dollar (SGD)</option>
</select>
```

How do I modify the code to fire off all the Ajax operations? Thank you :)

Comment: Which ajax 'operations' are you talking about???

Comment: This is a Wordpress plugin so I not able to pull out the specific Ajax operations. What happens is that it only changes the currency value but not the currency sign. If you manually change the selector it will change both the sign and the value. My guess is that I have to do something with the .change(); at the end of the code

Comment: You are hardcoding SGD parameter to call `localCurrencyChange()` method, seems wrong. But i'm really not sure what you are doing/expecting. Read your question again, don't you think it is missing some important infos???  Maybe try: `onchange="localCurrencyChange(this.value,lcValues1,1)"`

Comment: If you have a look at the site http://thehungrygeek.com/2015/11/17/australia-dairy-company/ and do a ctrl-f to "show currencies in" you will see the dropdown box, by default it is set at SGD, I want to use jQuery to change the selection on load - that is not difficult but the hard part is triggering the Ajax calls at the same time which is tied to the dropdown selection, which is the question I am asking

With that code it only changes the currency value but not the currency sign

Comment: @A.Wolff I'm not able to easily change the onchange value in the select element as it is from a Wordpress plugin

Comment: When i test it, it changes currency as expected: `HK$17 (ARS$28.48)`